# Swift array set value of index not working

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a method (contents below) where queue2 is just an [Int]. I printed a lot of things to see if everything was working up to a point.

```
public func cool(item: Int) {
    println(item)
    println(back)
    //queue2.insert(item, atIndex: back)
    queue2[back] = item
    println(queue2.description)
    println("done")
}
```

The problem is this fails at runtime and I don't know why. Apple docs say you can set the value of any index in an array with this notation, but it doesn't work. If I uncomment the commented line and comment out the one below it, everything runs fine but it doesn't provide the functionality I need. What gives?

Comment: It stops execution with a exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Comment: back = 0, and the queue is initiated to an array with capacity 20.

Answer (score 2):

If `queue2` is empty, this line is illegal no matter *what* `back` is:

```
queue2[back] = item
```

You cannot refer to an index that doesn't exist, and an empty array has no indexes (indices).

Comment: As for what happens when you use `queue2.insert(item, atIndex: back)`, the problem here is that you say "it doesn't provide the functionality I need", but you have not explained what that functionality _is_. That code is doing exactly what you are asking it to do; neither it, nor we, have any way of knowing what _else_ you might have had in mind...

Comment: how can i do that if i want? as its not posssible but i want to do that? can i realy do that?